# How to get balance using smartcontract in the new CDT

Tags: smart-contract

Is there a way to access the balance(of EOS or any token for that matter) of a given account using smart contract in the new CDT?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In latest token contracts to get balance you need to use a static function:

```
auto balance = eosio::token::get_balance(token_contract, token_holder_name, symbol_code);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this command to get balance through cleos tool `cleos get table eosio.token user accounts` as shown in this snippet you can use your contract name instead of **eosio.token** and use user's account by replacing **user** in snippet to get your token balance.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I am aware of the cleos command, I was more interested in directly accessing the eosio.token balance through an external smart contract

Comment: can you share exactly what you trying to do ?

Comment: I am developing a smart-contract which returns EOS after a command. I wanted to check the balance for EOS to see if enough EOS is available to return

Comment: Have look at this it may helpful for you https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4360

Comment: Anytime brother :)